# How do I place the QScrollBar on the content of the QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

I want to make a scrollbar that fades in and out depending on usage. I subclassed QScrollBar and got the look that I want. The problem is that the scrollbar is placed next to the content. How do I instead make it go on top of the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new QScrollbar which I connected to the original via signals and then used `widget->setParent` and then `widget->setGeometry()` to paint it on top

Answer (score 0):

I quicker solution is to reparent the `QScrollBars` that the `QScrollArea` creates and add it to a new `QLayout` to position it how you want.

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea();

QScrollBar *scrollBar = scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar();
scrollBar->setParent(scrollArea);
scrollBar->setFixedHeight(20);//required for later

QVBoxLayout *scrollAreaLayout = new QVBoxLayout(scrollArea);
scrollAreaLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);//use whatever margins you want
scrollAreaLayout->addStretch(1);
scrollAreaLayout->addWidget(scrollBar);
```

This gets the basic functionality working, however the `QScrollArea` still adds space where the scrollbar would have been. To remove this, subclass `QProxyStyle` and override `pixelMetric()`.

```
#include <QProxyStyle>

class StyleFixes : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    int pixelMetric(PixelMetric metric, const QStyleOption *option = Q_NULLPTR, const QWidget *widget = Q_NULLPTR) const override
    {
        if(metric == PM_ScrollBarExtent)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return QProxyStyle::pixelMetric(metric, option, widget);
    }
};
```

Then just apply it in main.cpp

`QApplication::setStyle(new StyleFixes);`

This will remove the arrows on the scrollbar however so you'll need to style it yourself.